# Find out what pattern was matched when using a LIKE query?

Tags: sql, string, oracle, sql-like, oracle9i

If I was to perform a normal query with a bunch of LIKE statements in it. Would it be possible to return which search term actually resulted in the row being returned?

So if I ran :

```
 select cand_id 
 FROM cand_kw 
 WHERE client_id='client' 
 AND (  ( UPPER(kw) LIKE '%ANDREW%' AND UPPER(kw) LIKE '%POSTINGS%' ) 
     OR ( UPPER(kw) LIKE '%BRET%' ) 
     OR ( UPPER(kw) LIKE '%TIM%'  )) ) )
```

And it returned some rows of results is there a way to tag on which term was actually matched in the row? So if '%ANDREW%' was what caused this row to be returned I could then show that information.

The data base engine is oracle 9i and I realize that this is normally a function something like full text searches that this database is not setup to handle so I am just trying to fake it in way.

Comment: Post CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements. And write the expected output. Explain how to get your desired result from your inputs. Also, 9i is long gone. Kindly upgrade to newer version of Oracle.

Comment: Just so you know, Oracle 9i does have Text capability built-in, it just needs your DBA to run a script and issue some grants.

Comment: @APC Is it possible to return keywords and scores from this full search text capability?

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit tricky, because more than one keyword may match. You could use a `CASE` expression in the `SELECT` clause, but then you would get the first matching keyword only.

Another approach would be to put each keyword on a separate row, use a join to filter the original table, and then aggregate the list of matching keyword.

So:

```
SELECT c.cand_id, LISTAGG(k.kw, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY k.kw) matches
FROM cand_kw c
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 'ANDREW' kw FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL SELECT 'POSTINGS' FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL SELECT 'BRET' FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL SELECT 'TIM' FROM DUAL
) k ON c.kw LIKE '%' || k.kw || '%'
GROUP BY c.cand_id
```

Comment: this query does not actually run for me. ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: @user794846: my bad, I forgot `FROM DUAL`. Fixed.

Comment: i still get the same issue

Comment: also there could NOT LIKE clauses in the query :select cand_id FROM cand_kw WHERE client_id='client' AND (( UPPER(kw) LIKE '%ANDREW%' AND UPPER(kw) LIKE '%POSTINGS%' AND UPPER(kw) NOT LIKE '%TIM%' ) OR ( UPPER(kw) LIKE '%BRET%' AND UPPER(kw) NOT LIKE '%TIM%' ))